# How do you synchronise an operation on a struct with operations on its members?

Tags: c++, c++17, x86-64, c++20

Anthony Williams introduces the lock-free stack in Concurrency in Action. This relies on the following data structure:

```
struct counted_node_ptr
{
    uintptr_t count;
    node* ptr;
};
using atomic_cnp = std::atomic<counted_node_ptr>;
```

One of the operations on an `atomic_cnp` is:

```
counted_node_ptr increment(atomic_cnp& some_atomic_cnp) {
    counted_node_ptr old;
    while(!some_atomic_cnp.compare_exchange_weak(old,{old.count+1,old.ptr}));
    return old;
}
```

The intent of this operation should be achievable with `LOCK XADD`, however, as written this gets implemented as a `LOCK CMPXCHG16B` in a loop. The advantage of `LOCK XADD` is that a *wait-free* 'top()' function could then be added to the interface. However I cannot find a way to express this in C++ using `fetch_add`. How can this be achieved?

In C++20, will it be possible to get an atomic reference to a struct to synchronise with an atomic reference to one of its members?

Comment: You'd have to use a union hack of an `atomic<counted_node_ptr>` with a `struct{ atomic<uintptr_t> ac; atomic<node*> ap; };`  And of course that would be UB that merely happens to work.  See [How can I implement ABA counter with c++11 CAS?](//stackoverflow.com/a/38991835).  In C++20 *maybe* you can get away with using atomic_ref on the whole thing vs. single members; IDK how the standard defines synchronization in that case when an atomic wide load reads something that includes the result of a narrow release-store.

Comment: Following the union trick in the link I get assembly that looks good. CAS retries protect against tearing and relaxed memory ordering. However I need a FAA operation on [RDI+8] to *happen-before* a CAS on [RDI] by another thread. Will all hardware recognise this dependency?

Comment: I think you mean synchronize-with to establish a happens-before/after for *other* code?  If you *need* fetch_add to always happen before a CAS, you need some *other* synchronization between threads.  (Ordering is hard to talk about).  But if you mean sync-with, on x86-64, with them in the same cache line (because they're members of a 16-byte-aligned struct) yes I *think* so?  Do you mean a `lock cmpxchg16b` on the whole thing or *just* a `lock cmpxchg` of the other 8 bytes?  If the latter, I don't know if it's meaningful because you can't tell if the CAS read a new or old value.

Comment: And BTW, this all depends on the compiler using `lock cmpxchg16b`, or for GCC7 and later, libatomic using `lock cmpxchg16b`.  If your code runs on a first gen K8 without `cmpxchg16b`, it will have to fall back to locking so you're screwed.  (Or will SIGILL if you used `-mcx16` with earlier GCC so it inlined the instruction.  That might be preferable to data corruption)